# Why my object looks like this after using the shader editor and smart unwrapping it?

Tags: modeling, texturing

I have this 4k texture and I've unwrapped it with smart unwrap and looks awful, I´m using the shader to have this PBR material look on the drill bit.

What am I doing wrong?

The shader is not working well? Do I have to unwrap it in another way or form?
[image: This is how it looks in edit mode]

[image: This is how it looks in object mode]

I´ve done the shade smooth option and other things like mark the seams and unwrap the object in the traditional way.

Thanks in advance guys,

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a descriptive title that summarizes the content of the question

Comment: The first issue I can spot is that you have color plugged into your roughness. Roughness only takes B&W values (White = rough, black = shiny). What else do you find wrong about the look? What is the image supposed to look like?

Comment: Yeah, it is a metal... So the diffuse texture is a 4k image. Thank you for answering, I will try that